# How to get the child from parent without any selectors to child?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a use case where i have a parent div with only one child where the child may be strong, div, header or any other... I'm in need of a generic solution to get innerHTML of the child "Hello World"

```
 <div id="parent">
  <strong>Hello World</strong>
 </div>
```

What is the efficient way to do this in jquery or js???

Comment: Is it an immediate child?

Comment: `$("#parent").children()`?
or just JavaScript: `document.getElementById("parent").childNodes`

Comment: @ mishik Aahh seems to be so silly to ask this... din try the .children() !!!! Thanks for the quick reminder

Comment: Check my answer below. Straight and easy.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('parent').children[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#parent").children();
$("#parent").children(':first');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the first child, you could do `$('#parent').children().first().text()`, or, to get all children, `$('#parent').children().text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with jQuery:-

```
$("#parent").contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType == 3;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery it's easy....

```
      $('#parent').children('strong').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$("#parent").children().html()
```

Just JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("parent").childNodes[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions to use the native `childNodes[0]` have a bug.

In your example HTML, there is a `textNode` that appears before the `<strong>` element you want. You would need to loop through the childNodes until you get to a non-`textNode`. You'd also have the same problem if you tried `.firstChild`.

The native DOM `.children` property will work in your example, but be careful: in IE8 and prior versions it also includes comment nodes.

jQuery's `.children()` method filters out text nodes for you, so that's a much easier way to do it.

The suggestion to use jQuery's `contents()` combined with `.filter` to filter out the text nodes will work, but is unnecessary; you could just use `.children()` instead and let it do the work of filtering out text nodes.